# Broadcasts vs Handlers for data transfer

Tags: android-handler

First, I am new to Android and Java, but making steady progress.

I have a question about the use of BroadCast Receivers Vs Handlers for data transfer for Andriod 3.0 +
I currently have handlers embedded inside a run thread which receives data over a USB-Serial link into my Acer A200 tablet.
These handlers (7 at this time) explictedly transfer the received data to several activities which use Fragments to display the data for  several views.

Since some of the data is used on multiple displays/views, my question is whether it would be better to simply "Broadcast" the data from the run thread and let each activies' Broadcast receiver deal with the capture and display of the data or is the use of a Handler explictedly sending the data to each activity preferrable?

Any pros/cons for either approach would be appreciated.

Thanks

Ed